# Pathlib vs. os.path.join in Python

Tags: python, path, os.path, pathlib

When I need to define a file system path in my script, I use `os.path.join` to guarantee that the path will be consistent on different file systems:

```
from os import path
path_1 = path.join("home", "test", "test.txt")
```

I also know that there is `Pathlib` library that basically does the same:

```
from pathlib import Path
path_2 = Path("home") / "test" / "test.txt"
```

What is the difference between these two ways to handle paths? Which one is better?

Comment: Basically you can do it either way, it really doesn’t matter much. It probably boils down to what syntax you prefer. Personally I don’t like the slash being “abused” as a path concatenation operator, therefore I prefer os.path.join, but it’s really just a matter of taste.

Comment: As far as functionality goes, both do the same thing. It's mostly a matter of preference which one you like. https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/

Comment: You can do the same as `path_2 = Path("home", "test", "test.txt")` and forget about the slash

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`pathlib` is the more modern way since Python 3.4. The documentation for [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) says that *"For low-level path manipulation on strings, you can also use the os.path module."*

It doesn't make much difference for joining paths, but other path commands are more convenient with `pathlib` compared to `os.path`. For example, to get the "stem" (filename without extension):

os.path: `splitext(basename(path))[0]`

pathlib: `path.stem`

Also, you can use the same type of syntax (commas instead of slashes) to join paths with `pathlib` as well:

`path_2 = Path("home", "test", "test.txt")`

Comment: One issue with pathlib.path is when working with bucket `gc://` or `s3://` `pathlib` causes the prefix to be reduce to `gc:/` etc. so better to work with  os.join

Comment: @skibee In this case you can also use `cloudpathlib`